# Using firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I've got problem with using database values in app.
I can't find way to use them in app.

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        FirebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser()!!

        val uid = auth.getUid()!!
        val fireBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        userRef = fireBase.getReference("users")

        val ordersRef = userRef.child("$uid")
        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val username = dataSnapshot.child("names").getValue(String::class.java)
                val lastname = dataSnapshot.child("lastname").getValue(String::class.java)
                Log.d("Data",lastname)
                Log.d("Data",username)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("Data", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        }
        ordersRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener)
```

This is the way to retrive data from firebase.
I get it in logcat :

```
2020-01-26 15:09:31.480 13943-13943/com.example.odpodstaw D/Data: TestLastname
2020-01-26 15:09:31.480 13943-13943/com.example.odpodstaw D/Data: TestName
```

I'd like to use it in App
How to get it to varable?
in MainActivity I've got

`lateinit var name :String`
`lateinit var lastname :String`

how to get values from database to `name` and `lastname` in MainActivity?

I'm just learning and I really don't know how to do this and how to use this data in my app.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use the values outside of `onDataChange`, which isn't possible. For more on the why of this, and how to still have maintainable code despite this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519

Comment: There two answers there, one with a callback and using coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this fetch is happening inside the `MainActivity`, you can do the following in the callback where you receive the data:

```
val activity = this@MainActivity
activity.name = name
activity.lastname = lastname
```

This sets the properties on the MainActivity.

Comment: I don't understand yet. I need to get:
 "TestLastname" value as ```lastname``` in MainActivity and 
"TestName" value as ```name``` in MainActivity